# How to bevel edges smooth and rounded?

Tags: edges, bevel

I am trying to round edges but if I'm applying more segments it doesn't help.
[image: 1]

Comment: maybe check the Shape value in the Operator Box, or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hey, I found solution.
The problem was that in the bevel profile type was (Custom) I changed to (Superellipse)
Thanks!